# Getting and setting sharedpreferences

Tags: sharedpreferences

Can someone please explain what is wrong with this code?

```
SharedPreferences sortMethod = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("sortMethod", MODE_PRIVATE);
                                sortMethod.edit().putInt("myInt", 1).apply();
                                int myInt = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myInt", MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("myInt", -1);
```

Comment: Last statement, `getSharedPreferences("myInt", MODE_PRIVATE)`, should it be `"sortMethod"` instead of `"myInt"`?

Comment: @AaronHe thanks alot that worked. Put it as an answer so I can accept it. I really get mixed up with the names. I dont actually KNOW what "sortMethod" and "myInt" are referring to.

Comment: Not a problem. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read data from `SharedPreferences`, make sure the name is correct.

So, the last statement should be:

```
int myInt = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("sortMethod", MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("myInt", -1);
```